# Keep track of list values in multiple loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's assume we have the following situation:

```
for a, b, c, d in some_function('some_file.txt'):
    for i in range(1, 16):
        for x in json_data[str(i)]["commune"]:
            print json_data[str(i)]["commune"][str(x)]["code"].encode('utf-8')
```

- `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are `yield`ed from `some_function(...)`
- `i` obviously takes values in the range `1 <= i < 16`
- `x` represents an object from a *json* structure

Now, what I can't seem to find my head around is some way of going through each loop exactly once, but keeping track of the values so that I can start from there at the next iteration.

For example, let's imagine three lists:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

- In the first for, I'll have `1,2,3,4`
- In the inner loop I'll have `1` -> the first country
- In the second inner loop I'll have also `1` -> the first city from the first country

---

- In the second iteration, the first for, I'll have `5,6,7,8`
- In the inner loop I'll have again `1` -> the first country (there are still cities in this country)
- In the second inner loop I'll have `2` -> the second city from the first country

and so on...

Now, because the last `for` goes through a *json* structure (example [here](https://dpaste.de/VmuZ)), I have to go through all the values of it, always with different `a,b,c,d` but with the same `i` until the json values are finished.

**Practical example**

Imagine this as it follows:

- a user with a,b,c,d info logs into a website
- on that website there are two dropdowns (countries (`i`) and cities(`x`)). When all the cities in a country are wasted, go to the next country and so on.
  What I want is to get each city of a country, always with a different user.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: @Peilonrayz what do you mean ? How would yield help in this situation ?

Comment: The problem is that I want to also go to the next `a,b,c,d` after a _city_ is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your code, you want to care about `json_data` somewhere else.

```
def f():
    for a, b, c, d in some_function('some_file.txt'):
        for i in range(1, 16):
            for x in json_data[str(i)]["commune"]:
                yield a, b, c, d, i, x

for a, b, c, d, i, x in f():
    print json_data[str(i)]["commune"][str(x)]["code"].encode('utf-8')
```

Going from your description, you want to go through the outer loop `some_function` and the two inner loops at the same time.
This means you need to do two things:

1. Flatten the two inner loops.

   ```
   g = (
       (i, x)
       for i in range(1, 16)
       for x in json_data[str(i)]["commune"]
   )
   ```
2. `zip` through both loops.

   ```
   zip(some_function('some_file.txt'), g)
   ```

This should get you something simple like:

```
g = (
    (i, x)
    for i in range(1, 16)
    for x in json_data[str(i)]["commune"]
)

for (a, b, c, d), (i, x) in zip(some_function('some_file.txt'), g):
    print json_data[str(i)]["commune"][str(x)]["code"].encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try iterating manually with while loops,inside the nested loops,so you could for example say:

```
while(a != 0):
    while(b != 6):
        if(b%2 == 0):
             a++
        b++
 a++
```

this way it would increment even when your b number is even.(pun not intended)

Comment: For me the `while` loop in Python never feels right unless it is `while True:`

Comment: Sometimes i also struggle with it but the more direct control over the control flow can help.(Also you can do this with for loops,but for loops are severely limited in python in my opinion)